# How is GLKit's GLKMatrix "Column Major"?

Tags: c, ios, opengl-es, matrix, glkit

**Premise A**

When talking about "Column Major" matrices in linear memory, columns are specified one after another, such that the first 4 entries in memory correspond to the first column in the matrix. "Row Major" matrices, on the other hand, are understood to specify rows one after another, such that the first 4 entries in memory specify the first row of the matrix.

---

A `GLKMatrix4` looks like this:

```
union _GLKMatrix4
{
    struct
    {
        float m00, m01, m02, m03;
        float m10, m11, m12, m13;
        float m20, m21, m22, m23;
        float m30, m31, m32, m33;
    };
    float m[16];
}
typedef union _GLKMatrix4 GLKMatrix4;
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/1462441-glkmatrix4/1462416-m) on the `m` member says:

> A one-dimensional array of the matrix’s elements in column-major
>   order.

**Premise B**

A "row" in a GLKMatrix4 is a set of 4 floats declared horizontally (`[m00, m01, m02, m03]` would be the first "row"). Thus, those entries can be interpreted as mRowCol (`m12` would be the entry at row 1, column 2).

---

If we look at how those GLKMatrix struct members are laid out based on the order of the declarations, we see:

`[m00, m01, m02, m03, m10, m11, m12, m13, m20, m21, m22, m23, ...]`

Where the first 4 entries clearly represent the first *row* of the matrix, not the first column.

**Conclusion**

`m` is not actually Column Major, and the docs are wrong.

---

Now, I should note that I don't actually believe the conclusion, but the two premises seem pretty reasonable. Really, I distrust premise B the most, but it seems strange to define a "row" to be vertical and a "column" to be horizontal. Can someone explain this?

Comment: `float m00, m01, m02, m03;` is the declaration of the first _column_, even though it "_looks like_" a row.  This is where __Premise B__ falls down.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The declaration is a bit confusing, but the matrix is in column major order. The four rows in the struct represent the columns in the matrix, with m0* being column 0 and m3* being column 3. This is easy to verify, just create a translation matrix and check values m30, m31 and m32 for the translation components.

I am guessing your confusion is coming from the fact that the struct lays out the floats in rows, when they are in fact representing columns.

Comment: That, and that fact that I've always indexed into matrices by thinking m(row)(col), not m(col)(row). Thanks.

Comment: @MattWilding That's exactly what tripped me up. But `m(row)(col)` is how you access a _row major_ matrix, ie row first, then column.  What confuses things is, although MATLAB is "column major", it still has a row-major indexing convention of `m(row,col)`.

Comment: We tend to think that a variable/member named "mXY" is the element for the X-th row and Y-th column of the matrix, but since the matrix is declared as being column major, the first "subindex" (in this case, X) of each member's name is the column.

Answer (score 10):

This comes from the OpenGL specification --

[image: column major]

The point of confusion is exactly this: as others have noted, we index a column major matrix *with the first index indicating the column, not the row*:

- `m00` refers to *column=0, row=0*,
- `m01` refers to *column=0, row=1*,
- `m02` refers to *column=0, row=2*,

MATLAB has probably done a lot to indirectly contribute to this confusion, while MATLAB indeed [uses column major for it's internal data representation](http://www.matlabtips.com/columns-and-rows-are-not-the-same/), it still uses a *row major* indexing convention of `x(row,col)`.  I'm not sure why they did this.

Also note, that OpenGL by default uses *column vectors* -- ie you're expected to post multiply the matrix by the vector it transforms, as `(MATRIX*VECTOR)` in a shader.  Contrast with `(VECTOR*MATRIX)` which is what you would for a row-major matrix.

[It may help to look at my article on row major vs column major matrices in C](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/06/06/what-is-the-difference-between-row-major-and-column-major-matrices/).

### Column major is counter-intuitive when laying out matrices in code

The more I look at this, the more I think it is a mistake to work in column major in C code, because of the need to mentally transpose what  you are doing.  When you lay out a matrix in code, you're restricted by the left-to-right nature *of our language* to write out a matrix row by row:

```
float a[4] = { 1, 2,
               3, 4 };
```

So, very naturally looks like you are specifying by row, the matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

But if you are using a column major specification, then you have actually specified the matrix

```
1 3
2 4
```

Which is really counter-intuitive.  If we had a [vertical (or, "column major" language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Su_shi-calligraphy.jpg) then specifying column major matrices in code *would* be easier.

Is all of this another round-about argument for Direct3D?  I don't know, you tell me.

### Really, why does OpenGL use column major matrices then?

[Digging deeper](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/math/matrix/column-vec.html), it appears that the reason this was done **was in order to be able to "post multiply" matrices by vectors as `(MATRIX*VECTOR)`** -- i.e. to be able to use **column (major) *vectors* like**:

#### Column major matrix multiplication

```
┌ 2 8 1 1 ┐ ┌ 2 ┐
│ 2 1 7 2 │ │ 2 │
│ 2 6 5 1 │ │ 2 │
└ 1 9 0 0 ┘ └ 1 ┘
```

Contrast this with having to use row vectors:

#### Row major matrix multiplication

```
[ 2 2 2 1 ]  ┌ 2 8 1 1 ┐ 
             │ 2 1 7 2 │
             │ 2 6 5 1 │
             └ 1 9 0 0 ┘
```

The deal is, ***if matrices are specified as row major, then you "should" use row vectors and pre-multiply matrices by the vector they are transforming***.

The reason you "should" use row vectors when you use row-major matrices is *consistent data representation*: after all, a row vector is just a 1 row, 4 column matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The problem in **Premise B** is that you assume that *A "row" in a GLKMatrix4 is a set of 4 floats declared horizontally ([m00, m01, m02, m03] would be the first "row").*

We can verify that simply by checking the value of `column` in the following code:

```
GLKMatrix3 matrix = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
GLKVector3 column = GLKMatrix3GetColumn(m, 0);
```

Note: I used `GLKMatrix3` for simplicity, but the same applies to `GLKMatrix4`.

Comment: Yeah, that confirms my suspicions. Thanks.